# How to return a promise from a go block?

Tags: clojurescript

The question is how to send to a nodejs app the result of a go block

- i found a solution with callback
- but i need a solution with promise

**Promise solution**?

Clojurescript app

```clj
(defn foo []  
  (go 1))

;;how to change foo,wrap to promise?, so node app can await to get  the 1
;;i used 1 for simplicity in my code i have something like
;;(go (let [x (<! ...)] x))
```

Node app

```js
async function nodefoo() {
  var x = await foo();
  console.log(x);     // i want to see 1
}
```

**Callback solution** (the one that works now)
So far i only found a way to pass a cb function, so this 1 goes back to node.js app

Clojurescript app

```clj
(defn foo1 [cb]
  (take! (go 1)
         (fn [r] (cb r))))
```

Node app

```js
var cb=function () {....};
foo1(cb);   //this way node defined cb function will be called with argument 1
```

But i dont want to pass a callback function, i want node.js to wait and get the value.
I want to return a promise.

Comment: Please update question to add more detail on what the `go` block is doing and/or needs.

Comment: @AlanThompson i tried to make it more clear, and i changed the nodejs app

Comment: This is possibly an X/Y problem. If the consuming node function is async and expects a Promise to await, why do you need a go block? And if you have a go block where you can just write to a channel once a Promise resolves, why do you need an async consumer? etc. etc. What problem are you *actually* trying to solve here? I'm not saying this can't possibly make sense, but it smells a little funny. Also, and again I realize there are a few legit use cases, why clojurescript with node.js? Why not just use clojure?

Comment: my code already has go blocks, and from clojurescript was easy to wait them with <! , now i want to wait them from node, and i dont know the way.  I cant use clojure i need my code to be called from nodejs app

Comment: Should be something like this `(defn returns-promise [] (new js/Promise (fn [resolve _reject] (go (resolve (<! (some-async-op)))))))`. I didn't actually test that out, but should be close.

Comment: Yes jared thank you alot, i got a similar answer from the people at slack, i will send the answer here, when i test it again, maybe useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function takes a channel and returns a Javascript Promise that resolves with the first value the channel emits:

```clj
(defn wrap-as-promise
  [chanl]
  (new js/Promise (fn [resolve _] 
                    (go (resolve (<! chanl))))))
```

Then to show usage:

```clj
(def chanl (chan 1))
(def p (wrap-as-promise chanl))
(go
  (>! chanl "hello")
  (.then p (fn [val] (println val))))
```

If you compile that and run it in your browser (assuming you called `enable-console-print!`) you'll see "hello".

Comment: thanks again Jared : ) i tested that code in node also it was working fine, without the chanl argument, because i called from node. I had the chanl already in the code inside the go.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to extend the ManyToManyChannel type with `extend-type`.
Here's a naif implementation using a similar `wrap-as-promise` function

```
(require '[clojure.core.async.impl.channels :refer [ManyToManyChannel]])

(defn is-error? [val] (instance? js/Error val))

(defn wrap-as-promise
  [channel callback]
  (new js/Promise
       (fn [resolve reject]
         (go
           (let [v (<! channel)]
             (if (is-error? v)
               (reject v)
               (resolve (callback v))))))))

(extend-type ManyToManyChannel
  Object
  (then
    [this f]
    (wrap-as-promise this f)))

(def test-chan (chan 1))

(put! test-chan (new js/Error "ihihi"))
(put! test-chan :A)

(defn put-and-close! [port val] 
  (put! port val)
  (async/close! port))

(-> test-chan
    (.then (fn [value] (js/console.log "value:" value)))
    (.catch (fn [e] (js/console.log "error" e)))
    (.finally #(js/console.log "finally clause.")))
```